# How do I correctly write jquery script

Tags: jquery

I have been attempting to change the text that appears for various links within an html list.

What I want to do is this:
**So in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/ecqt5ysL/),  using jQuery - I want to go to #athletic-group-dropdown, in the first ul change the ‘a’ text that is within the second li from "News" to "Overview"**

I have tried various scripts and this gets me the closest but:

```
jQuery( “#athletic-group-dropdown ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass( "overview-switch" );
jQuery(".overview-switch a:contains(‘News’)”).html(“Overview”);
```

```js
jQuery("#athletic-group-dropdown ul li:nth-child(2) ").addClass("overview-switch");
jQuery(".overview-switch-lst a:contains('News')").html("Overview");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="athletic-group-dropdown">
  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Peaches</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Grape</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have attempted several scripts with various issues, but I am close with the above, but it changes several of the links instead of the specific one I want.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

**This is just an example list, in the actual page that are 6 columns of links with, so I want to be able to pick the needed column via the ID and then go into the ul/li, find the 'a' and change that text.**

Comment: Really a new question but I added a second answer for that.  I will leave it to you to determine which one using that

Comment: no, same question.  I just want to change the text of a specific 'a', that is within ul/li that is within an ID.

Comment: Please, follow the "Minimal Reproducible example". Right now you are passing different examples around, which confuses the answers. If there are multiple `a` inside each `ul`, add multiple `a` in your example. Right now you are only showing one `a` and asking to change just the `a` inside the second `li`. We don't know if you just want to change the second `li` of the first `ul`, all the `li` in all the `lu` or to change the `a` which have the "News" word independently of its position.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a really big workaround. You don't need to add a class and later do a class selection.

The code is pretty straight-forward:

```js
$("#athletic-group-dropdown ul:first-child a").text("Overview");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="athletic-group-dropdown">        
    <ul class="athletic-menu">
      <li>Tea</li>
       <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>  

    <ul class="athletic-menu">
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Peaches</li>
    </ul> 

    <ul class="athletic-menu">
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Pear</li>
      <li>Grape</li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

The selector explanation is easy:

- First get the group with `#athletic-group-dropdown`.
- Just after that, we get all the `ul` that are the first-childs, becasue there's only one level of `ul` list we do not need to use the "direct" selector (`>`), so just use `#athletic-group-dropdown ul:first-child`.
- Then, the same with the `a`. Becasue there's only one `a` element insde each `ul`, we just select it `#athletic-group-dropdown ul:first-child a`.
- We have `a` selected and then change the text.

If you actually need to add a class for whatever reason, you can do it with one line, without doing "double selection":

```
$("#athletic-group-dropdown ul:first-child").addClass("overview-switch").find("a").text("Overview");
```

Comment: Hi Jorge - I tried your first script and it changes everything in the first column.  Not just the specific a

Comment: I often wonder about using this very long selectors to get an element I already know I will change. Why not give the element an id? That ist much clearer, easier to read and also much faster in execution

Comment: @user1176783 You said "in the first ul", so I just changed the first ul in the HTML you given. We may need more info on this.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Because this seems an exercise to learn about selectors. By the way, IDs must be unique and in modular websites they are a problem. I prefer to use classes as they don't need to be unique in the entire webpage.

Comment: Hi Jorge - "I want to go to #athletic-group-dropdown, in the first ul change the ‘a’ text that is within the second 'li' from "News" to "Overview""

Comment: Hi Jorge, i have an updated fiddle using your script above https://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/ecqt5ysL/20/ - when you run it, see how it changes all the links text.  I think i need to incorporate nth-child because it may be the first child in id/ul, but the 3rd child in another id/ul.

Comment: Then your question and example HTML is a bit incorrect @user1176783 xD You only have one `a` inside it actually.

Comment: Is this Fiddle what you expect? https://jsfiddle.net/r0fb23vc/ @user1176783

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better way but `.overview-switch-lst` is NOT the class you added

```js
jQuery("#athletic-group-dropdown ul li:nth-child(2) ").addClass("overview-switch");
jQuery(".overview-switch a:contains('News')").html("Overview");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="athletic-group-dropdown">
  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Peaches</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Grape</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Perhaps a better selector and chain with a filter.  Update for your additional requirement (a new question but...)

```js
function updateText(index,oldtext, newtext) {
  $("#athletic-group-dropdown").find("ul")
    .find("li>a").filter(":contains('"+oldtext+"')")
    .eq(index).addClass("overview-switch").html(newtext);
}
updateText(1,"News", "New Overview");
```

```css
.overview-switch {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}


/* just to show the class added */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="athletic-group-dropdown">
  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Peaches</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Grape</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh i see what you mean by the NOT the class, i have edited the class in my question .

Comment: That second example should provide you with some flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an id?

```js
$('#dropDownChangeableText').html("Overview");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="athletic-group-dropdown">
  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li><a id="dropDownChangeableText" href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Peaches</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Grape</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the current list of links doesn't have classes on li items and until I get to the repo to hardcode classes/id's, i want to use jquery as a work around for the moment

Answer (score 0):

Perfect solution here - really clean and concise and flexible:

```
$("#athletic-group-dropdown ul:eq(1) li:eq(2) a")
    .text("not peaches")
    .attr("href", "http://google.com");
```