# How to correctly use jquery nth-child to change text of link

Tags: jquery

I am re-asking this question so hopefully it is less complicated:

With this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/ecqt5ysL/20/) example, how do I correctly use jquerys nth-child to change the text of a specific link?

```
<div id="athletic-group-dropdown">        
<ul class="athletic-menu">
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Tea</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>  

<ul class="athletic-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Peaches</a></li>
</ul> 

<ul class="athletic-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Car</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

- I may need to change 'news' in the first ul/li to 'Overview'
- I may need to change change 'peach' in the second ul/li to 'Bank'.

I attempted this:

```
jQuery( “#athletic-group-dropdown ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass( "overview-switch" );
jQuery(".overview-switch a:contains(‘News’)”).html(“Overview”);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "may need"? Do you need to or not? Don't use curly quotes`‘` or `“` instead of single or double quotation marks. Why aren't you just selecting the first, second, or third unordered list instead of doing the odd two-step you posted?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to use `nth-child`? Is it just for learning purposes?  If not, better off using `.eq(0)`.  `nth-child` is normally when you want to change multiple records (eg a whole column in a table, or, in your case Milk, Peaches *and* News together (`:nth-child(2)`)).  Equally, your 2nd "attempt" doesn't even include `nth-child` so it's really not clear what you're trying to achieve or why.

Comment: In relation to your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994639/how-do-i-correctly-write-jquery-script) - if you want to change a *specific* item and *you know which item it is*, then you can access that directly, eg `$("#athletic-group-dropdown ul:eq(1) li:eq(2)`).text("not peaches");`  (zero-based, so 1st item is `.eq(0)`) - there's no need to use `nth-child` if you've already limited to a specific parent.

Comment: WOW freedom-m - that worked, just one thing,  this script removes the actual url only one to change the text.

Comment: freedom-m - I will just add the entire url in html() like this .html("<a href='yahoo.com'>Overview</a>")

Comment: Why not target the `<a>` : `$("#athletic-group-dropdown ul:eq(1) li:eq(2) a).text("not peaches").attr("href", "http://google.com");`

Comment: GENIUS!!!!I would like to upvote this for you.  Could you add it as an answer.

Comment: You might want to look at the edit I made in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I correctly use jquerys nth-child to change the text of a specific link

`nth-child` is not the best solution for this scenario.

If you know the specific item to change (and don't want to change any others), then target that item directly:

```
$("#athletic-group-dropdown ul:eq(1) li:eq(2) a")
    .text("not peaches")
    .attr("href", "http://google.com");
```

nth-child is used to target multiple elements eg make all first li's bold (could also use :first-child, just an example)

```
$("#athletic-group-dropdown ul li:nth-child(0) a").wrap("<b>")
```

or used with more complicated options such as `:nth-child(even)` / `:nth-child(3n+2)` which isn't desired here

To answer the explicit question, you can use `:nth-child` instead of `:eq` (except 1-based vs 0-based), but it will not be as clear/obvious what the code does and *looks* like it should be changing multiple items:

```js
$("#athletic-group-dropdown > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(3) > a").text("not peaches")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="athletic-group-dropdown">
  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tea</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Peaches</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="athletic-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Car</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1

Answer (score 0):

Your link are not specific. You have 3 sets of 3 links. Think of it as you need to know what is where in order to change a specific `a` element. They would need to have `id`'s. Your fiddle is working you are changing the text value of element `a` that are in the child of `athletic-group-dropdown`

The first child is `athletic-menu` And it contains 3 `a` element

```js
//$(".athletic-menu li:first-child").addClass("overview-switch").find("a").text("Overview"); ///// all a element
//$(".athletic-menu1 li:first-child").addClass("overview-switch").find("a").text("Overview");// first a element of athletic-menu1
$("#item1").addClass("overview-switch").text("Overview");
$("#item2").addClass("overview-switch").text("Overview");
$("#item3").addClass("overview-switch").text("Overview");
```

```css
.overview-switch{
  background-color:#212121;
   color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="athletic-group-dropdown">        
<ul class="athletic-menu1">
  <li><a id="item1" href="#">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Tea</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>  

<ul class="athletic-menu2">
  <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a id="item2"href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Peaches</a></li>
</ul> 

<ul class="athletic-menu3">
  <li><a href="#">Car</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a id="item3" href="#">Grape</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Now again we have 3 `a` element because i refer to `li` first child of elements with it's `class` name instead of it's `id`. Turns out all your 3 lists have the same `athletic-menu` class so the first li child of any element with that class is afected.

So it all comes down to what you want to do. So for one single a element you could just use specific identifier for each a element.